# UIAlertController pushed up and offscreen by modal view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have a `viewController`, presented by a `navigationController`, and when I press a button I do two things: first I present a `UIAlertController`, which appears just fine. Then in 2 seconds, I modally present a second `UIViewController`, and when it slides upward, (maybe due to a bug in UIKit) it literally pushes the `UIAlertController` upward as well until it is almost off-screen. What could be going on to cause this?

In another experiment with `UIAlertView` (deprecated), this does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIAlertController` is always presented as a modal, and one view controller shouldn't present two modals at the same time. Typically there is a warning in the console when you attempt to do this, but regardless the behavior is undefined. If you need to present a modal and have an alert over the top as well, you need to have the second viewcontroller present the alert after it becomes visible.